# Convert Map<> to Map<String,String>

Tags: java, list, dictionary, type-conversion, comparator

I have some code like this, I try to sort value from List of Map by the key given in sortby. The code is below :

```
final String sortby = "first";
    List<Map> lm = new ArrayList<Map>();
    Map m = new HashMap();
    m.put("id", "eka");
    m.put("first", "ek");
    m.put("last", "a");
    lm.add(m);
    m = new HashMap();
    m.put("id", "adit");
    m.put("first", "adi");
    m.put("last", "t");
    lm.add(m);

    for(Object M : lm){
        System.out.println(M.toString());
    }

    Comparator<Map<String,String>> mapComparator = new Comparator<Map<String,String>>() {
        public int compare(Map<String,String> m1, Map<String,String> m2) {
            return m1.get(sortby).compareTo(m2.get(sortby));
        }
    };

    Collections.sort(lm, mapComparator);

    for(Object M : lm){
        System.out.println(M.toString());
    }
```

but it can't compare using comparator because incompatible data types. How can I convert `Map<>` to `Map<String,String>` or any other suggestion so the comparator can compare all data type?

Comment: why don´t you just make the initial `List<Map>` a `List<Map<String,String>>`?

Comment: because the input for the map is not always String

Comment: This is what happens when you use raw types.

Comment: @EkaCahyaPratama Using raw types isn´t the best option here. You might want to reconsider the map then and maybe wrap the input in something like a common wrapper class for the different possible classes.

Comment: How about a `Map<String, Comparable<?>>`? Or `new Comparator<Map<? extends Object,? extends Comparable<?>>>()`.

Comment: @KevinEsche thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MapComparator<K,V extends Comparable<V>> implements Comparator<Map<K,V>> {

  public int compare(Map<K,V> m1, Map<K,V> m2) {
     return m1.get(sortby).compareTo(m2.get(sortby));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using raw types for the `lm` and `m` variables. You can change your code to the following:

```
List<Map<String, String>> lm = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
// ...

m = new HashMap<>();
// ...

for (Map<String, String> map : lm)
{
    // ...
}

// ...

for (Map<String, String> map : lm)
{
    // ...
}
```

Note that the `ArrayList` constructor uses `<>` instead of `<Map>`, indicating that the type from the left-hand side of the assignment (`Map<String, String>`) is inferred. You could also write it like this:

```
 List<Map<String, String>> lm = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>()
```

The same applies for the `HashMap` constructors.

Comment: OP said, that his input isn't always a String, so he can't use `Map<String, String>` for the source map.

Comment: how it is different from @KevinEsche answer in the comment ?